# how to easily apply css to gagawa?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, json

I have written a java program that generates an html dynamically using `com.hp.gagawa.java.elements`

for example. the following code:

```
head.appendChild(new Link().setRel("stylesheet")
        .setHref("/RoutingRegression/html_pages/css/delta_samples.css"));

H3 h3 = new H3().appendText("Alternatives:");
body.appendChild(ImmutableList.of(h3, table));

Tr tr2 = new Tr();
Th th_2_0 = new Th()
        .setColspan("2")
        .setStyle("width:60%")
        .appendText("From all alternatives:");
tr2.appendChild(th_2_0);

table.appendChild(ImmutableList.of(tr2));
```

now, a css guy took a resulted html source

and added some style and css to it.

I find it a bit hard to manipulate `gagawa` so his css changes will apply.

What do you suggest so i will apply his style over my html?

go for another approach of saving JSON file and generating the html based on this Json data with js ?

or most easy is to stick with current `gagawa`, and style it slow and safely?

Comment: Did you find the answer to that yet? please share the source